# PHP - Non-Blocking, Outgoing TCP Connections - How?

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

I'm somewhat familiar with the various methods of performing non-blocking IO within PHP, but the answer to this question seems to be eluding me. Let me describe what I am attempting to do:

I would like to have a static class called "Monitor" that I can throw various messages at. The class should then connect to an external TCP server and send those messages along - But I do not want to wait for that to happen. Everything, from the initial connection to the external server through the sending of the message should happen asynchronously, while my script has already moved along to other things.

Is this possible? I am currently attempting to use fsockopen(), stream_set_blocking(), etc...

Comment: What's wrang with `stream_set_blocking` (that you currently used)?

Comment: Hi did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about is basically multi threading (which is not the usual way to use php). You can check [this article](http://blog.motane.lu/2009/01/02/multithreading-in-php/) to see how to do it. I wouldn't recommend to use this in production though.

Comment: I believe you are right. Like I said earlier, I understand the basics of the various ways of doing multiplexed sockets within PHP, etc..., but what I'm talking about here actually takes that concept one step further, beyond what is possible with PHP (aside from the various forking mechanisms, which I don't want to use). Thank you for clarifying that.